# Browser display PHPExcel sheet instead of open "Save dialog" when export

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpexcel

I´m trying to export some data from mysql to "PHPExcel".
I would like to have a "Save dialog" rather than saving the file on server.
 I have google it but cannot find anything more than "Add another header".. so i have been adding alot of headers :)

But both Chrome and Firefox will only display the sheet.
No, Save dialog opens.
Why?

To save the file on server works just fine!

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"results.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");

//Load db connection
require("conf.php");
//Check if usr is logged in
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
  header("Location: index.php");
  die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}

//Check IF post
if(!empty($_POST['objNr'])){
  //Store post in var
  $objNr = $_POST['objNr'];


  /** Error reporting */
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  //Load phpexcel includes    
  require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

  /** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
  include '../Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

  // Create new PHPExcel object
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  // Set properties
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Nr');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Höjd');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Typ');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Längd');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'AV');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Öppningar');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'Vikt');


//Fetch data from DB
$query = "SELECT * FROM element WHERE objekt_nr = '$objNr' ORDER BY length(element_nr), element_nr ASC";
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
//Insert på first row after heading 
$row = 2;
while($value = $stmt->fetch()){
    //Set start Column
    $column = "A";

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['element_nr']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['hojd']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['typ']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['langd']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['avdrag']."");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['oppningar']."");

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($column++.$row, $value['vikt']);

    //INCREASE Row Nr
    $row++;
}

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($objNr);


// Write file to the browser
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('file.xlsx');

}
else{
  echo 'Välj objektnummer..';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this `$objWriter->save('php://output');` instead of `$objWriter->save('file.xlsx');`

Comment: Thank you. I had this before. But i´m so tired searching for headers, so i forgot to change it back ;D